# ¿Como hacer que un botón cambie de color, en Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

me interesa saber como puedo hacer que un botón cambie de color dependiendo de algunas condiciones, por ejemplo: que en la interfaz de Netbeans aparezca un mapa de mesas de un restaurante, en el cual aparezca un botón en cada mesa de color verde sí la mesa está disponible, y que aparezca en rojo cuando la mesa esté ocupada. Muchas gracias(:

Comment: Saludos, Liz. Te invito a leer [¿Cómo elabora una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, quisiéramos saber qué has intentado hasta ahorita y de esa manera brindarte una orientación en lo que debes hacer.

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo que tienes ya

Comment: Hola Liz, ¿podrías intentar agregar más detalles de lo que ya has realizado y de ser posible aclarar un poco más lo  que buscas? Yo lo he intentado pero me han rechazado la edición y me interesa saber las respuestas que obtienes. Gracias

Comment: Hola, tal vez esto te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207927/duda-al-crear-un-componente-java-en-netbeans/

Answer (score 1):

Si codificamos tu enunciado la solución que buscas debería ser similar a esta:

```
if(ocupada) {
     boton.setBackground(rojo);
}else {
     boton.setBackground(verde);
 }
```

Para realziar eso de manera más sencilla a en los ActionListener de los botones, cuando se presione el botón comprueba se está disponible, en el caso de estar disponible entonces pone el botón a rojo y pasa a estado ocupado, y de la misma manera en el caso contrario.

Comment: Hola Sergio, lo ideal sería que aparezca el estado de disponibilidad (color del botón) antes de que el usuario presione en él. ¿Cómo podría lograr esto?

Comment: Lo defines por defecto a verde.