# Crear un componente personalizado en netbeans usando Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero crear un componente (Bean) en NetBeans, me refiero a crear un componente que luego pueda utilizar desde la paleta de componentes; que cuando lo inserte en un *frame* el botón que inserte, me cambie de color el botón cada vez que lo pulse.

Yo he hecho esto pero no sé si voy bien encaminado, porque cuando inserto posteriormente el componente (el botón) en un `JFrame` no hace nada.

```
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class LblBotonColores extends JButton implements Serializable {
    private boolean cambioColor;

    public boolean getCambioColor() {
        return cambioColor;
    }

    public void setCambioColor(boolean cambioColor) {
        this.cambioColor = cambioColor;
    }

    public LblBotonColores() {

        JButton miBoton = new JButton("Hola Mundo");

        if(getCambioColor()){

            miBoton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }else{
            miBoton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con componente "Bean"?

Comment: Me refiero a crear un componente que luego pueda utilizar desde la paleta de componentes. En este caso un botón. Lo que quiero es que cuando se  lo inserte en cualquier JFrame al pulsar luego el botón cambie de color el botón. No sé si me explico bien, no obstante gracias. @Crack81

Comment: @NathanRothschild así se les llama en el [tutorial de sun](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/), algunos lo conocemos como benforms por el nombre con que salen en el netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te hice [un tutorial](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/componente-personalizado-en-netbeans-beanform/) de como lograr lo que quieres ya que son muchos pasos.

El problema esencial que veo en tu código es que no hace lo que tenías pensado por que no hay datos que te permitan conocer el estado actual.

Una buena técnica para evitar este tipo de problemas es hacer primero lo que denomina modelo de datos, es decir, primero detectar que sujetos tenemos, en nuestro caso se trata de saber si el color es azul y de si deberemos de cambiarlo.

Agregamos las variables a la clase

private boolean cambioColor;

```
private boolean azul = true;

public boolean getCambioColor() {
    return cambioColor;
}

public void setCambioColor(boolean cambioColor) {
    this.cambioColor = cambioColor;
}
```

Y en nuestro constructor nos aseguramos de que haya un estado inicial

```
 setBackground(Color.blue);
```

En el método para cambiar el color simplemente ponemos nuestra condición para que se active si es que deseamos que tenga la capacidad de cambiar de color y que cambie al color opuesto en base a la otra variable

```
  if (cambioColor) {
        if (azul) {
            setBackground(Color.red);
            azul = !azul;
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.blue);
            azul = !azul;
        }
    }
```

Y bueno.. hemos terminado, el resultado es un botón que puedes usar en tu paleta de componentes de netbeans, si deseas que se peuda modificar desde la apleta de propiedades debes ponerle setter y getter a las variables configurables, por ello azul no sale como puedes ver.

[image: selector de propiedades de netbeans]

tras correr el ejemplo verás que te meustra tu botón y que tiene el comportamiento que buscabas

[image: frame con botón que ya trae el comportamiento de cambiar de color la darle click]