# Editar con código propiedades de un campo creado desde la vista diseño de Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, matisse

¡Hola!

**Objetivo:** Cambiar las propiedades de un campo mediante código, cuando el campo fue creado desde el editor gráfico de Netbeans.

**Qué estoy haciendo:** En la captura se ve cómo cree un JFrame y dentro de él un jTextArea, todo esto desde la interfaz gráfica de Netbeans.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante código quiero cambiar la tipografía de ese jTextArea. Para esto, cree un método llamado *xxx()*, que llamo justo después de instanciar la clase principal, con el fin de que los cambios de tipografía se vean reflejados en el JTextArea. En esta otra captura verán cómo queda esto que estoy haciendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado:** Si bien lo que estoy haciendo no manda ningún error, tampoco funciona.

¿Alguna sugerencia para lograr mi objetivo?

Comment: como sugerencia evita poner tu código como imágen, no todo el mundo puede verlas, ya sea por debilidad visual o porque el proxy de su empresa lo borra (fortinet cof cof). Lo ideal es ponerlo como texto.

Answer (score 1):

En la ventana de propiedades si te fijas bien hay una secicón llamada `Código` o `Code` según el idioma de tu Netbeans.

[image: opciones útiles en la ventana de propiedades]

Para personalizar los componentes tienes tres opciones:

- Código de creación personalizado (Custom Creation Code)
- Código antes de la creación (Pre-Creation Code)
- Código después de la creación (Post-Creation Code)

De esta manera puedes personalizar los componentes y mantener aislado el código de interfaz de usuario de el código que conforma la funcionalidad ( también llamado lógica de negocio ).

Por ejemplo puedes agregas en código de pre-creación

```
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC,12);
```

Y en código de post-creación:

```
jtextArea1.setFont(font);
```

Y el código en la sección init components se verá algo similar a:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
  private void initComponents() {
      jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC,12);
      jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
      jTextArea1.setFont(font);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
      jTextArea1.setRows(5);
      jTextArea1.setText("this is some text");
      jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
```

Aunque es importante hacerte notar que:

- los imports del código usado allí deberás agregarlos tú a mano posteriormente si no estaban agregados
- El código se regrenerará cada vez que lo abras en el IDE, así que no será editable en el editor en la vista de código, sino únicamente en la vista de diseño.
- al abrirlo en netbeans con el editor en la vista de código no será editable (por si tampoco había quedado claro)

Si piensas reusar tu componente entre frames solamente arrastrando y soltando para que se autogenere el código desde la paleta de componentes te recomiendo consultar mi respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207927/crear-un-componente-personalizado-en-netbeans-usando-java?fbclid=IwAR23bwT9oeUFB0Q_hoRghWmzE2Jzvwwuv13dBrbvjdE3XiqcffAIoVvFSVo)

Comment: Tienes razón, ya veo esos campos en mi Netbeans. Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: no hay de que, normalmente los que usan la etiqueta netbeans no preguntan realmente acerca de netbeans y es bueno ver preguntas como la tuya.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré respuesta a mi problema. Al parecer no busqué lo suficientemente bien en mi primera googleada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438221/how-to-modify-add-code-to-the-initcomponents-method-in-java-using-netbeans

La idea que plantee originalmente era correcta, sólo que el método xxx() no había que llamarlo en el método main(), sino el constructor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]