# ¿Como crear componentes para un JFrame?

Tags: java-8, java-awt

Intento crear componentes, en java como los botones o labels, de tal manera que cada uno sea independiente y pueda actualizarse independientemente del otro. Intente algo asi:

```
public class Bit extends Component{
    private boolean carga;
    private boolean mostrarCarga;
    private int x;
    private int y;
   
    private String label;

    public Bit(boolean carga, int x, int y){
        this.carga = carga;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        mostrarCarga = true;
        
    }

    public boolean isCarga() {
        return carga;
    }

    //setter y getter de x e y
    
    public void mostrarCarga(boolean mostrarCarga) {
        this.mostrarCarga = mostrarCarga;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.setColor(asignarColor());
    
      g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
        
      if(mostrarCarga){g.drawString(label, x + 23, y + 5);}
                
        
    }

    private Color asignarColor() {
        if(carga){
            label = "1";
            return Color.RED;
        }else{
            label = "0";
            return Color.BLUE;}
    }
    
    
}
```

pero al probarlo solo se agrega el ultimo que agregue

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Prueba de Animación");
   
      
    Bit a = new Bit(true, 50, 60);
    a.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(a);
    Bit b = new Bit(false, 100, 60);
    b.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(b);
    Bit c = new Bit(true, 150, 200);
    c.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(c);
}
```

en este caso el unico que se agregaria seria el Bit c
(Obvie los getters y setters de x e y)

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el constructor o la declaración de los atributos? Es para descartar posibles errores que no estás viendo.

Comment: @PabloLozano listo, gracias por el interes

Comment: ¿No debería extender de JComponent en lugar de Component? No se deben poner componentes AWT (heavyweight) dentro de contenedores Swing (ligeros), ya que no respetarán el layout correctamente

Comment: @PabloLozano lo acabo de intentar, pero pasa lo mismo, solo se dibuja el ultimo que añadí, tambien probe cambiando el metodo por paintComponent, tampoco funciona

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Crear un componente personalizado en netbeans usando Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207927/crear-un-componente-personalizado-en-netbeans-usando-java)