# ¿Cómo adecuar los componentes al aumentar o disminuir el tamaño del jframe o panel?

Tags: java, java-swing, layout

Al presionar un botón maximinar(btnmaximizar), mi ventana se aumentará de tamaño y quiero que los componentes como jlabel, txtfield se adecuen su tamaño al nuevo tamaño de la ventana, lo mismo para un botón minimizar(btnminimizar)

[image: diseño actual]

Ejemplo:

[image: maximizado]

Comment: podrias agrear tu codigo, una captura y si te es posible como quieres que se vea exactamente en su modo maximizado?

Comment: Al presionar el boton maximizar la ventana crezca el doble o un poco más, y los componentes se adecuen al nuevo tamaño, que esten centrados. Lo mismo para un botón minimizar, obviamente a la inversa. El tamaño de mi ventana es width 620 y height 458 private void btnMaximizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
       
}
para que veas el interfaz y sus componentes
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_5W4UQuS5HfXyAbrbLhb9Sah4Am4s6sq?usp=share_link

Comment: con centrados te refieres a que sean del mismo tamaño pero que estén todos en el centro dejando un borde enorme alrededor?

Comment: por cierto si has intentado algo seria mejor que agregaras el codigo ya que aca son las 12 am y sinceramente tampoco dispongo de demasiado tiempo para ayudarte

Comment: Si eso, esten centrados pero se queden con el mismo tamaño. Sin el borde

Comment: he editado la pregunta agregando una imagen de como podría quedar, si no fuera así edita la imagen tu para mostrar que quieres :)

Comment: Si, así como has editado la imagen, que ocupe toda la pantalla. Perdón por no ser tan especifico, primera vez que uso esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que deseas mete todo en un JPanel.
A tu JFrame agrégale ese panel usando el `BorderLayout` para especificar la posición Centro

```
getContentPane().add(miNuevoPanelPrincipal, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Como intuyo que usas [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans), puedes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. agrega un nuevo panel desde la paleta de componentes en el editor visual [matisse](/questions/tagged/matisse)
2. ponle al nuevo jpanel el miso layout que tienes actualmente en el JFrame desde la pestania del navegador
3. selecciona todos los elementos excepto el nuevo panel con el mouse y arrastralos dentro del JPanel para que queden exactamente igual
4. selecciona tu elemento JFrame en la pestania navigator
5. cambia el layout a `Border Layour (Default)` desde el menu contextual del elemento Frame
6. Selecciona tu nuevo `Jpanel` y en la pestania de propiedades en la parte inferior dentro de la seccion `Layout` ponle a la entrada `direction` el valor `Center` (casi siempre aparece al final al elegir este layout)

Como veo que estas personalizado tus componentes de la misma manera te recomiendo [crear tus propios componentes personalizados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207927/crear-un-componente-personalizado-en-netbeans-usando-java) para poder reutilizarlos después